# Cookie destroys when i refresh page more then once

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

i have following snippet, now what happens is that when i refresh page for the 1st time i get the cookies by `print_r($_COOKIE);` i can see cookie present by when i refresh page more then once i cant see my respected cookie i.e `result`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
        jQuery(window).unload(function() {
            // Remove the cookie
            jQuery.removeCookie("result");
        });
      });
```

And following is my JSON sucess

```
   success: function(data)
                    {
                        var server_result = data.result;
                    jQuery('#search-main-area').empty();
                    jQuery.cookie("result", server_result, {expires: 3});
                    var results = jQuery.cookie("result"); // Sample 2
                    jQuery('#search-main-area').append(results);
                    }
```

Comment: You're calling `.removeCookie()` and wondering why your cookie disappears?

Comment: @MarcB: i am assuming `unload` means when this window unloads and a new window with new URL loads.

Comment: @noobie-php: http://api.jquery.com/unload/  `Even a page reload will first create an unload event.` Technically there's no real difference between hitting refresh, and clicking on a link that points at the page you're on. Both will initiate an http request. Even if that request simply reloads the page out of cache, it still counts as an initiated "going somewhere else" action, where the somewhere else is "right here".